# Angular-material-calendar, to customize css for dates, dateClass is not properly applicable

Tags: angular

I am using angular-material-calendar. I used sample data which have dates and type. Based on type dates should be colored differently. For example:-

```
{date: 2010-07-04, type: Holiday} for holiday color:-green.
{date:2019-10-10, type:outage}, for type:-outage, apply color:-red
```

.
The issue I am facing, css is applicable to some dates and types, not to all

```
  <div class="row-item" *ngFor="let month of months">
        <mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass()" [startAt]="month" [selected]="selectedDate"
          (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)"></mat-calendar>
      </div>
```

Below is stackblitz link:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-c-p-5htnub?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Css for this is in style.css.

Css is not applicable to all the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you has a very complex dateClass function, use some like

```
dateClass() {
    return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
      //we get the value in date in format yyyy-MM-dd
      const dateSearch=date.getFullYear()+'-'+
                      ('0'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+
                      ('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2)

      //search in the array
      const items=this.datesArray.find(x=>x.date==dateSearch)

      //return if found it, the "type", else null
      return (items?items.type:null)

    };
  }
```

Comment: how abput apply css class 'linkable' if linkable of dates are true? I tried this 
`     //search in the array
      const items=this.datesArray.find(x=>x.date==dateSearch);
      const item = this.datesArray.find( y => y.linkable)
      //return if found it, the "type", else null
      return (items?items.type:null, item ? 'linkable' : '')`

Comment: you can return `items?items.type+(items.linkable?' linkable':''):null`

Comment: I gave css for linkable :- .linkable {text-decoration: underline !important;} but its not applicable and I see that class in DOM. If linkable is true then underline the date

Comment: use `.linkable > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {  text-decoration: underline !important;}`see your stackblitz forked https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-c-p-ajkmkd?file=styles.scss